# How do I select related subtopic videos with the highest episode number?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I have a subtopics table and a videos table and they are related. My videos table looks like the following

```
|id| sub_topic_id| episode | title   | description |
|1 |      1      |      1  | Hello   |    Test     |
|2 |      1      |     10  | Hello2  |    Test     |
|3 |      2      |      1  | Hello3  |    Test     |
```

What I want now is to get the video for `every subtopic` with the `highest episode number` and paginate on them.
In my example I would get 10 for the subtopic 1 and 1 for the subtopic 2.

I hope it is clear what I mean, maybe someone could help me.
What I have tried in eloquent for now is

```
$videos = \DB::table('videos')->where('episode', \DB::raw("(select max(`episode`) from videos)"))->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Do you just want sub_topic_id and episode or do you need the `id` too ?

Comment: The highest episode for the related subtopic, so I think no id is needed? Sry dont understand

Comment: I added an answer giving the `highest` episode for each `sub_topic_id`, if you need the `id` of that row too, then i need to change the query to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query;

```sql
SELECT videos.*
FROM videos
         JOIN (
    SELECT sub_topic_id, MAX(episode) AS maxEpisode
    FROM videos
    GROUP BY sub_topic_id) AS subQuery
              ON subQuery.maxEpisode = videos.episode AND subQuery.sub_topic_id = videos.sub_topic_id;
```

This is the eloquent version;

```
$subQuery = DB::table('videos')
    ->groupBy('sub_topic_id')
    ->select('sub_topic_id', DB::raw('MAX(episode) as maxEpisode'));

return Video::join(DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql() . ') as subQuery'), function ($join) {
            $join->on('subQuery.maxEpisode', '=', 'videos.episode');
            $join->on('subQuery.sub_topic_id', '=', 'videos.sub_topic_id');
        })->get(['videos.*']);
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work either gives me back an array collection instead of an object collection and it is not paginateable?

Comment: Same I need to get object to then display the attributes in my view.

Comment: @TheNastyPasty i replaced the query builder with Eloquent, i am not sure whether i get you right.

Comment: I am missing my attributes like title, description and so on.

Comment: @TheNastyPasty your question doesn't include anything related to title, description etc.

Comment: I am sorry will update that immediatly, but thought these attributes are automatically in my results. Is it possible to paginate on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217410/discussion-between-thenastypasty-and-ersoy).

Comment: @TheNastyPasty that’s completely different query, the question i was asking related to this, do you need ‘id’ too. I will try to update it. Let you know

Comment: @TheNastyPasty please check the answer now. I tested on my local, looks like working

Comment: What is $subquery? It say undefined

Comment: @TheNastyPasty `A subquery is a SQL query within a query`. What your problem is greates-n-per-group as i updated the tag in your question. I managed to do it with subquery.  do you have any problem in there ?

Comment: I get an exception $subQuery is undefined.

Comment: @TheNastyPasty sorry, forgot the include first part of the query - updated now.

Comment: Np but look a little bit overkill for such a thing :D Could I use paginate here?

Comment: Yeah thats the query for this kind of requirements. Sure you can since it returns collection. @TheNastyPasty

Answer (score 1):

**set your episode column structure to integre**
and then try

```
$videos = \DB::table('videos')->orderby('episode',DESC)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for you answer, but this does not work it gives me all epsiodes in desc order. What I need is all videos for the related subtopics with the highest episode number. Like in my example above. There are 3 records but only the two highest episodes were in the result.

Comment: when it episode will be a number it will return highest number in descending